# What kind of bulbs does this lamp need?

Tags: light-fixture

I have recently gotten hold of a lamp that seems to require some weird bulbs. I can't seem to figure out what type of bulb goes in there... It looks like it could be in the G9 family, but there is no sleeve to insert the bulb in.

Here is a picture of the socket :
[image: the weird socket]
[image: another angle]

Edit: close up
[image]

Edit 2: size reference
[image]

I have tried unscrewing the screws, but the cap it attached to the wires.

Does anyone have a clue what bulbs I need?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A close-up of the socket would help; if you aren't allowed to post the image, post the URL and someone will be along to edit the image in.

Comment: I have added a close up, but it not as clear as I'd hoped. I'll try to take a better one.

Comment: Thanks for the picture. What do you mean by "but the cap it attached to the wires"?

Comment: If I remove the screws, I still cannot remove the bit at the end. At first I thought it was some sort of cap covering the actual socket, but is **is** the socket. The two slits are where the bulb's prongs should go (I think).

Comment: But was it that yellow behind the "left prong"

Comment: I'd need to get a copy of WD-6 and check the dimensions, but this sure resembles a 2-15R...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, It kinda does, but it seems like the prongs on 2/15R bulbs are angled from each other

Comment: @norcaljohnny, I'm not sure, I'll try to figure it out

Comment: Do you know what voltage bulbs it needs? Do you know its country of origin?

Comment: The lamp has 6 such sockets, that should total around 100 watts. I'm pretty sure the lamp comes from here in Canada.

Comment: Based on the pic in @norcaljohnny's answer, I'd say you were correct in your assessment that this is a G9 bulb. Since this appears to be in a chandelier of some sort, I would submit that the bulb does _not_ sit in any sort of protective sleeve, but that the chandelier itself is supposed to protect the bulb from physical contact/damage, but that the bulb remains bare within the fixture. Did you ever get this sorted out?

Comment: @FreeMan We never did sort it out. The lamp ended up on the curb (it was picked up quickly though, hopefully by someone with more bulb knowledge!)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is a light bulb connection as is and shown in the picture. Without the cap removed and having the ability to see what's behind it, I do not think it may be answered. Look at the photo below for the different light bulb connections.

## [image]

**NOTE:** Whoever gave the thumbs down did me wrong. When I posted my answer the first 2 picks were all that was posted and and the text was rewritten after showing those are screws in the fixture. I simply did not remove my answer because I was not sure if we are supposed to.

This type of light bulb (connectors) is referred to as **Double Contact Bayonet light bulbs**.

My bedroom ceiling lights all use them and they can be found at most hardware stores like Home Depot, Lowes, and even Walmart.

**Removing the light bulb:** Push in and turn counterclockwise. When it stops turning it can be pulled out. About a 1/16 of a turn. (opposite for replacing the bulb.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what seemed like holes in the picture are actually screws.

Comment: is that that wire sitting behind the cap

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question